# css rotate doesn't work correclty

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have one problem with css rotation.

I created this [demo](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/YwVZKL) from codepen.io

In this demo you can see blue div the lower right corner of the page. When you click this div then the links will opening with rotate animation. But the rotate is not working correclty. I have tryed `transform-origin` but doesn't worked.

What i am missing in here ? Anyone can help me in this regard ?

CSS

```
.menu {
  float:left;
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  border-radius:45px;
  opacity:0;
  text-align:center;line-height:45px;
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
-o-transform:rotate(0deg);
}
.menu img {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
.activeMenu {
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
  display:block;
  opacity:1;
  transform-origin:50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
-o-transform:rotate(360deg);
-webkit-animation:  2s infinite linear;
-moz-animation:  2s infinite linear;
-o-animation:  2s infinite linear;
-ms-animation:  2s infinite linear;
animation:  2s infinite linear;
}

.activeMenu:nth-child(1){
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
 -webkit-transition: all .1s ease .15s;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease .15s;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease .15s;
    -ms-transition: all .1s ease .15s;
    transition: all .1s ease .15s;
}
.activeMenu:nth-child(2){
  -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .30s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .30s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .30s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .30s;
    transition: all .3s ease .30s;
}
.activeMenu:nth-child(3){
  -webkit-transition-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease .45s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease .45s;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease .45s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease .45s;
    transition: all .5s ease .45s;
}
.activeMenu:nth-child(4){
  -webkit-transition-delay: 4s;
 -webkit-transition: all .7s ease .60s;
    -moz-transition: all .7s ease .60s;
    -o-transition: all .7s ease .60s;
    -ms-transition: all .7s ease .60s;
    transition: all .7s ease .60s;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="postButtonsWrap" id="psbtn">
  <div class="menu"><img src="http://www.nabi.res.in/Images/fb.gif"></div>
  <div class="menu"><img src="http://www.budget.com/budgetWeb/images/common/twitter1.png"></div>
  <div class="menu"><img src="http://www.nijmegenindialoog.nl/wp-content/uploads/in.ico"></div>
  <div class="menu"><img src="http://www.yellowpagescr.com/images/google-plus-icon-png-transparent.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: @HarshSanghani codepen.io site is enough for it i think.

Comment: "But the rotate is not working correclty" In what way? And in which Browser? Works fine for me in Chrome on OSX

Comment: Your code pen demo works perfectly for me also.

Comment: @SlashmanX Please look carefully in demo page. facebook,twitter,linkedin images will be come rotate but there are something went wrong. The rotate will not working with origin.

Comment: @HarshSanghani the rotate need to work in center.

Comment: I've checked the rotations multiple times and I finally see what is bothering you. They are more like bouncing than rotating, because they go over the top edge.

Comment: @c00ki3s yes you understood it. The problem is exactly that.

Comment: A problem description including "doesnt work correctly" is too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your css a little. Here is the complete document I've tested.
I've also added comments where I made some changes. Got them icons spinning like you wanted to.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .postButtonsWrap {
                position:fixed;
                width:45px;
                height:45px;
                background-color:#469FE2;
                bottom:10px !important;
                right:10px !important;
                border-radius:45px;
                -webkit-border-radius:45px;
                -moz-border-radius:45px;
                padding:5px;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
                -webkit-transform-origin: right top 0px;
                box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
            }
            .activePm {
                width:190px;
                border-radius:30px !important;
                -webkit-transform-origin: right top 0px;
            }
            .menu {                 
                float:left;
                width: 0px;
                height 0px;
                opacity: 0;
                border-radius: 45px;
                line-height: 45px;
                text-align:center;

                -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
                -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
                -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
            }
            .menu img {
                width: 25px;
                height: 25px;
                margin-top: 9px;
            }
            .activeMenu {
                /*MODIFIED THE ACTIVE MENU*/
                -webkit-animation: 2s infinite linear;
                -moz-animation: 2s infinite linear;
                -o-animation: 2s infinite linear;
                -ms-animation: 2s infinite linear;
                animation: 2s infinite linear;

                -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
                -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
                -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
                transform-origin: 50% 50%;

                width:45px;
                height:45px;
                display:block;
                opacity:1;

                /*PLACED YOUR BORDER RADIUS HERE*/
                border-radius: 45px;

                -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
                -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
                -o-transform:rotate(360deg);                    
            }
            .activeMenu:nth-child(1){
                -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
                -webkit-transition: all .1s ease .15s;
                -moz-transition: all .1s ease .15s;
                -o-transition: all .1s ease .15s;
                -ms-transition: all .1s ease .15s;
                transition: all .1s ease .15s;
            }
            .activeMenu:nth-child(2){
                -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
                -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .30s;
                -moz-transition: all .3s ease .30s;
                -o-transition: all .3s ease .30s;
                -ms-transition: all .3s ease .30s;
                transition: all .3s ease .30s;
            }
            .activeMenu:nth-child(3){
                -webkit-transition-delay: 3s;
                -webkit-transition: all .5s ease .45s;
                -moz-transition: all .5s ease .45s;
                -o-transition: all .5s ease .45s;
                -ms-transition: all .5s ease .45s;
                transition: all .5s ease .45s;  
            }
            .activeMenu:nth-child(4){
                -webkit-transition-delay: 4s;
                -webkit-transition: all .7s ease .60s;
                -moz-transition: all .7s ease .60s;
                -o-transition: all .7s ease .60s;
                -ms-transition: all .7s ease .60s;
                transition: all .7s ease .60s;
            }       
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
               $('body').on("click", ".postButtonsWrap", function(){
                 $("#psbtn").toggleClass("activePm");
                 $(".menu").toggleClass("activeMenu");
               });   
            });     
        </script>
    </head>  
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="postButtonsWrap" id="psbtn">
              <div class="menu"><img src="http://www.nabi.res.in/Images/fb.gif"></div>
              <div class="menu"><img src="http://www.budget.com/budgetWeb/images/common/twitter1.png"></div>
              <div class="menu"><img src="http://www.nijmegenindialoog.nl/wp-content/uploads/in.ico"></div>
              <div class="menu"><img src="http://www.yellowpagescr.com/images/google-plus-icon-png-transparent.png"></div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```